# Custom jQuery Plugin Error But Still Works

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm making a jQuery slider plugin and it works, however I keep getting this error in the  JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'interval'
```

The error says it's coming form these two lines (the code in-between each curly bracket):

```
if(settings.interval) {
    $(this).interval(settings.interval);    
}

if(settings.transition) {
    $(this).transition(settings.transition);
}
```

This is my first jQuery plugin and I can't figure the problem out. Any ideas what's causing the error?

Here is the code in action [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Enijar/dMyyG/2/)

Comment: There is no `$.interval()` and you haven't defined one either.

Comment: I defined interval in the settings variable. Is this wrong? Can anyone show me a code example of how to rewrite this?

Comment: What is `$(this).interval(settings.interval);` supposed to do?

Comment: @janfoeh As this is my first jQuery plugin. I followed this tutorial and it says to use it: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins

Comment: There's no mention of any interval in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like janfoeh mentioned you don't need the lines you quoted in your question. The reason they have those checks in the tutorial you linked to is because those settings options are set to `null` by default. But for your plugin, those settings are not optional i.e., if you didn't have values for them, your plugin wouldn't do anything.

So I suggest setting defaults for the `interval` and `timeout` options and *allowing* them to be overridden instead of *requiring* them to be set ever time you use the plugin. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/48xDy/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. I get now what I did wrong. I'll know this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the lines you quoted above - they have no purpose. I have updated your fiddle.